# transparent sticky navbar not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I found a code for the sticky navbar on [this](https://codepen.io/sonorangirl/pen/XmRBjq) site, I copied the code and tried to run on my laravel blade file. Following is the complete code.output comes like [image: this]

I copied the code in following way.
  `CSS`
  `JS`
  `HTML`
please let me know what to do, I am beginner and trying to learn. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
It's expected that you **make an effort to solve the problem *before* asking**. You need to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates or reproduces the issue **specifically** described in the question. It looks like bootstrap.css is not properly reference in the laravel site.

Comment: I tried all myself first, tried to make it work. after hours of effort it wont work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code not working with Bootstrap 4. Use the correct CSS and JS link.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  
.image {
  background-color: #490D40;
  background: url(https://sonorangirl.github.io/Earth-Quotes/img/google-earth-view-South-Iceland3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 570px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.image .heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
.image p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 60px;
}
.image p .btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.image p .btn:hover {
  color: #C57ED3;
  border-color: #C57ED3;
}

.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #C57ED3;
  border: 1px solid #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white !important;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #C57ED3;
  border: 1px solid #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:visited {
  color: #C57ED3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #490D40;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  color: #C57ED3;
  background-color: #C57ED3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul {
  background-color: #490D40;
}

/* Solid class attached on scroll past first section */
.navbar.solid {
  background-color: #490D40;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
}
.navbar.solid .navbar-brand {
  color: #C57ED3;
  transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar.solid .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #C57ED3 !important;
  transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}

.about {
  background-color: #C57ED3;
  color: #490D40;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
  min-height: 200vh;
}
.about h2 {
  padding-top: 220px;
}
.about p {
  padding: 20px 80px;
}

</style> 
 
</head>

<body>
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Transparent to Solid Nav</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="image">
   <h1 class="heading">Main Heading</h1>
   <p><button class="btn btn-large">Big Button</button></p>
</div>
<div class="about">
   <h2>Main Description</h2>
   <p>Roll on the floor purring your whiskers off intrigued by the shower burrow under covers, and play time, rub face on everything, intently sniff hand, or pelt around the house and up and down stairs chasing phantoms. Attack feet. Damn that dog shake treat bag under the bed drink water out of the faucet for lick butt love to play with owner's hair tie. Swat at dog give attitude.</p>
</div>
   
</body>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Transition effect for navbar 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px, adds/removes solid class
          if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
              $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
          } else {
              $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
          }
        });
}); 
</script>

</html>
```

min-height: 200vh; by .about class is optional for testing.